# Understanding Linear Law.

Tags: linear-transformations

Today,I was asked this question in class by my teacher:

$y=5x^7$,transform it into a linear equation.

So what I did was this.

$y=5x^7$

$Y=mX+c$

where 
$Y=y$

$X=x^7$

$m=5$

$c=0$

However my teacher said it was wrong.

The correct solution should be

$log_{10} y =log_{10} (5x^7)$

$log_{10} y =log_{10} 5 +7log_{10}x$

where $Y=log_{10} y$

$X=log_{10}x$

$m=7$

$c=log_{10} 5$

I thought there is no unique solution in linear law?Why is the way I did wrong?My teacher didn't explain to class before he leaving.

Comment: What you wrote is technically correct: it is a change of variables that results in a linear equation equivalent to your original equation. A big advantage of your teacher's approach is that the transformation is the same regardless of the exponent. This makes it useful for fitting data to a power law. In your version you needed to already know that the exponent was 7.

Comment: So,his version can be used for any exponent?

Comment: But what if the question is $y=3x^3 +c$,where c is any constant?Do I do my teacher's way or let $Y=y,m=3,X=x^3$?

Comment: If there is an additive constant then you are right that logs don't help. Tour Idea would still go through the same.

Comment: So,in summary,if no constant, use log.If there is a constant,don't use log.

Comment: Ultimately follow what your class does. But that rule sounds reasonable to me.